# AWS S3: Delete a file x days after last modification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm struggling with the following use case in AWS S3 and life cycle rules:

- In my application, a user can ask for file deletion
- When it does i want to keep the file 90 days and then delete it

I don't want to delete the file 90 days after the date it was created (uploaded)

For example:

- I have a life cycle rule in my bucket that will expires files with tag "to_delete" 90 days after creation date
- I upload file for the first time in bucket: last modified date is today (creation date), let's say D1
- In 3 days i edit the file, i add the "to_delete" tag: last modified date is D1 + 3 days, let's say D3
- Will the life cycle rule apply 90 days from today (D1) or from today + 3 days (D3) ?

Comment: You don't edit S3 objects.  You create a new object replacing the old one.  So, the object will be deleted in D3.

Answer (score 1):

I just performed an experiment:

- I picked an object in Amazon S3 that was old
- I ran the `aws s3api put-object-tagging` command to add a tag to the object
- I then checked the `LastModified` on the object

**Result:** The `LastModified` timestamp *did not change*

Therefore, I would suggest a change to your process:

- When tagging the object, tag it with the desired **Deletion Date**
- Run a daily script (eg using AWS Lambda) that checks the tags on each object

  - If the Deletion Date tag indicates that the desired time period has passed, delete the object

Comment: that seems overkill to use a lambda to do this since, for me, life cycle rules are meant for this. How about i add a `to_delete` tag and a `to_delete` metadata when the user deletes the files. If my understanding is correct, if  a file metadata is added aws creates a copy of the file which would resolves the problem of the creation date

Comment: Yes, I think that metadata can only be "added" by copying the object over itself. That should change `LastModified`.

Comment: I even think that aws creates a new copy automatically when i add a new metadata on the file

Comment: after verification its not possible to add a new metadata on an existing object, we need to upload a new copy of the file with the metadata to its useless to me. So solution is to reupload file with `to_delete` tag

Comment: Please see my earlier comment... You can add metadata by copying an object over itself using `CopyObject()`. That is, the source and destination are the same object, but different metadata is specified.